# Why is the interchange of integration and summation allowed in this case?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

In a solution of a book of the integral:

$$\int_a^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+n)^{k+1}}\,dz, \;\; a\geq 1$$

I see the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( n+z \right )^{k+1}}\,dz &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{dz}{(n+z)^{k+1}}\\ 
 &= \cdots\\ 
\end{align*}$$

The rest of the solution is understable to me but not the interchange.
I was unable to prove that the fuction within the series converges uniformly... and I cannot think of something else that works here e.g monotone convergance thoerem or Tonelli Theorem.

Comment: I think you have a typo and intended $dz$ instead of $dx$. I'm also confused about the roles of $n$ and $k$ between your two lines. Anyway, Fubini-Tonelli applied to the product of the Lebesgue and counting measures implies that you only need to prove that when you put absolute values inside the sum, you get a finite solution.

Comment: Fixed for $dz$. Well $n$ is the index of the series and $k$ is just any fixed natural number. Suppose that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+k)^{4}}$ meaning that $k=3$.

Comment: My confusion is that in the first line you have $(z+k)^{n+1}$ while in the second line you have $(n+z)^{k+1}$. It is not clear which one you mean.

Comment: I think it's ok.. got your point... I have just written it so quickly.. i did not check later for typos...

Now, what do I have to prove? OK, I take absolute values and then what?

Comment: Analysis is far from my strong suit, but why can't you use Tonelli's Theorem?

Comment: Well, how can you bound $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n+z|^{k+1}}$? (Your bound will of course depend on $z$ and $k$.)

Comment: @Callus I did not say I cannot use Tonelli's Theorem ... I said I don't see how it will work here...

Comment: I thought Tonelli said you can switch the order of integration if the function was non-negative on the domain.  Nothing about boundedness. http://planetmath.org/tonellistheorem

Comment: Yeah... that was what I thought too. @Ian.. I cannot see how to bound the series... Any more hints?

Comment: @Tolaso I think Tonelli just applies directly.  The function is non-negative on $\mathbb{N}\times[1,\infty)$, so you can switch the order of integration/summation, using counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Callus Hmm.. let me think about that...

Comment: Oh, $z$ is a positive real. So yes, Tonelli (not Fubini or the hybrid Fubini-Tonelli) lets you interchange. Basically, in Tonelli, if you get $+\infty$, then you get $+\infty$ no matter what order you do things in, and if you get a finite number then you get the same finite number regardless of order. The caveats are that you need nonnegativity and $\sigma$-finiteness. But here nonnegativity is trivial, and the space is indeed $\sigma$-finite, since the Lebesgue measure and the counting measure are both $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Ian Thank you Ian for the clarification...

Comment: Why doesn't monotone convergence work?

Comment: @GPerez Don't we use Monotone Convergence for interchanging limit and sum or limit and integral..? It works here? Honestly , I cannot see how it will work... as I could not Tonelli's theorem as well...

Comment: Monotone convergence also works in this particular case.

Comment: @Tolaso A series is nothing more than a limit of partial sums. If each new term of the series is positive, then obviously $\sum_1^n \leq \sum_1^{n+1}$, and the convergence is monotone. Therefore you can interchange the limit and the integral, in this case the series and the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion above the answer to my question is:

We are allowed to interchange summation and integration by the use of **Tonelli's Theorem** because that thing that lies in the series is positive.

And everything is going its way.

*Thanks for the help!!*